# Error while running a shiny app to create a predictive model and a corresponding plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, linear-regression

I am new to shiny and just built this shiny app using the ToothGrowth data available in R. A summary of the data is as follows:

```
 str(ToothGrowth)
'data.frame':   60 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ len : num  4.2 11.5 7.3 5.8 6.4 10 11.2 11.2 5.2 7 ...
 $ supp: Factor w/ 2 levels "OJ","VC": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ dose: num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...
```

My ui.R file is as follows:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application 
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Tooth length prediction"),
    
    # Sidebar with options selectors
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            h3(helpText("Select:")),
            selectInput("dos", label = h4("Dose Value"), choices = list("0.5", "1" ,"2")),
            selectInput("sup", label = h4("Supplement Type"),
                        choices = list("OJ" = "OJ", "VC" = "VC"))
 
        ),
        
        # Show a plot and regression line
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("distPlot"),
            h4("Predicted tooth value is:"),
            h3(textOutput("result"))
        )
    )
))
```

and my server.R file is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

head(ToothGrowth)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # build linear regression model
        ToothGrowth$dose <- as.numeric(ToothGrowth$dose)
        fit <- lm( len~dose + supp , ToothGrowth)
        # predicts the length
        pred <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(dose = input$dos,
                                                  supp = input$sup
                                                 ))
        # Draw the plot using ggplot2
        plot <- ggplot(data=ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y = len))+
            geom_point(aes(color = supp), alpha = 0.3)+
            geom_smooth(method = "lm")
          
        plot
    })
    output$result <- renderText({
        # Renders the text for the prediction below the graph
        fit <- lm( len~dose + supp , ToothGrowth)
        pred <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(dose = input$dos,
                                                  supp = input$sup
        ))
       
    })
    
})
```

When I run the app, I get this error:
 `Error in : variable 'dose' was fitted with type "numeric" but type "character" was supplied`

I don't see any rendered plot created by ggplot nor an outcome for the prediction output of the linear model as you can see below:
[image]

I truly appreciated if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Much appreciated!

Regards

Comment: Also, how can I show the plot using `plot_ly`? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `as.numeric()` to `dose` in server part:
replace `input$dos` with `as.numeric(input$dos)`

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

head(ToothGrowth)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # build linear regression model
    ToothGrowth$dose <- as.numeric(ToothGrowth$dose)
    fit <- lm( len~dose + supp , ToothGrowth)
    # predicts the length
    pred <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(dose = as.numeric(input$dos),
                                              supp = input$sup
    ))
    # Draw the plot using ggplot2
    plot <- ggplot(data=ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y = len))+
      geom_point(aes(color = supp), alpha = 0.3)+
      geom_smooth(method = "lm")
    
    plot
  })
  output$result <- renderText({
    # Renders the text for the prediction below the graph
    fit <- lm( len~dose + supp , ToothGrowth)
    pred <- predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(dose = as.numeric(input$dos),
                                              supp = input$sup
    ))
    
  })
  
})
```

[image]

Comment: I am using `ggplotly` to plot the graph and added this line to the code: `plot <- ggplotly(plot)` & `plot` to the server.R file. However, the plotly file is shown in the viewer and not presented in the shinyapp.

Comment: Use `plotlyOutput` in the UI and `renderPlotly`in the server part